# Structs or Objects in Powershell 2

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, tuples

Does the latest version of Powershell have the ability to do something like JavaScript's:

```
var point = new Object();
point.x = 12;
point.y = 50;
```

If not, what is the equivalent or workaround?

**UPDATE**
Read all comments

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The syntax is not directly supported by the functionality is there via the add-member cmdlet's.  Awhile ago, I wrapped this functionality in a general purpose tuple function.

This will give you the ability to one line create these objects.

```
$point = New-Tuple "x",12,"y",50
```

Here is the code for New-Tuple

```
function New-Tuple()
{
    param ( [object[]]$list= $(throw "Please specify the list of names and values") )

    $tuple = new-object psobject
    for ( $i= 0 ; $i -lt $list.Length; $i = $i+2)
    {
        $name = [string]($list[$i])
        $value = $list[$i+1]
        $tuple | add-member NoteProperty $name $value
    }

    return $tuple
}
```

Blog Post on the subject: http://blogs.msdn.com/jaredpar/archive/2007/11/29/tuples-in-powershell.aspx#comments

Answer (score 14):

For simple ways, first, is a hashtable (available in V1)

```
$obj = @{}
$obj.x = 1
$obj.y = 2
```

Second, is a PSObject (easier in V2)

```
$obj = new-object psobject -property @{x = 1; y =2}
```

It gives you roughly the same object, but psobjects are nicer if you want to sort/group/format/export them

Answer (score 6):

Sorry, even though the selected answer is good, I couldn't resist the hacky one line answer:

```
New-Object PsObject | Select-Object x,y | %{$_.x = 12; $_.y = 50; $foo = $_; }
```

Comment: Personally I like the multiassignment syntax:
... | %{$_.x,$_.y,$foo = 12,50,$_ }

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
$point = New-Object Object |
    Add-Member NoteProperty x ([int] 12) -passThru |
    Add-Member NoteProperty y ([int] 15) -passThru
```

Regarding one of your comments elsewhere, custom objects may be more useful than hash tables because they work better with cmdlets that expect objects to have named properties. For example:

```
$mypoints | Sort-Object y   # mypoints sorted by y-value
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$point = "" | Select @{Name='x'; Expression={12}} ,@{Name='y'; Expression={15}}
```

or more intuitively

```
$point = "" | Select x,y
$point.x=12; $point.y=15
```